# Apple MacBook Pro OSX 10.9 refuses to print to a printer

Tags: macbook-pro, printing

New to apple so is there a way to debug why a laptop will not print to a printer?

It is an HP Color Laserjet 3000n. The laptop will recognize the printer and stay in a sending mode or sometimes the printing job will vanish. Works fine for other monochrome laserjets.

Tried removing and readding the printer with no success. there also does not seem to be any drivers for download from HPs website.

Comment: Have you tried powering the printer itself off and on again?  Several of the HP printers in our office will continue to work fine for PC printing but Mac print jobs seem to vanish.  Power cycling the printers almost always resolves it for us.

Comment: Hey, yes I did try that.

Comment: Drivers and software for this printer are available for Mac OS X. Go to the HP Support Center and choose "Mac OS X" for your OS, not "Mac OS X 10.9". Install the drivers and software and you should be good to go.